# FloodRisk plugin not working in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3

Does anyone know the equivalent of FloodRisk plugin for QGIS 2 in QGIS 3? Or alternatives to FloodRisk that work in QGIS 3?

Answer (score 2):

As in the repository, the devs answers for the port of the plugin in QGIS 3.x :

Posted on April 1st (I think it's not a joke) :

> The currently published version of floodrisk is still the one for QGIS
>   2.8. The new version, called Floodrisk2, for QGIS 3.x is ready, but not yet published as we are updating the user manual to describe new
>   features of the plugin. The publication will take place as soon as
>   possible. Leonardo Mancusi

[*source*](https://github.com/FloodRiskGroup/floodrisk/issues/4#issuecomment-478466765)

The latest commit was on June 10, it's still active.

Wait or contact them if you really want this *floodrisk2* version.

---

FloodRisk 2 for QGIS 3 has been released on QGIS Plugin Repository on August 20th 2019: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/floodrisk2/